# Game-like loading screen for three.js in html & javascript with setInterval does nothing or goes wrong

Tags: javascript

So I have a project and using three.js, thus it takes some time to load everything.
For the loading screen I thought of some messages (hints and pieces of information) that would be displayed, like in video games.
Unfortunately, it only works one time, or really fucks up and everything flickers and shows all of the texts.
Something is off and I really don't know what. I had the function in the setInterval, outside of it, gave the counter to the function or not. Didn't matter.
Currently the following is my javascript code:

```
const loadingtexts = document.querySelectorAll(".loading-text");
  let counter = 0;

  let myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    animateText(counter);
    //counter++;
  }, 5000);
  function animateText(counter) {
    console.log(counter);
    if (counter < loadingtexts.length) {
      loadingtexts[counter].style.display = "none";
      loadingtexts[counter + 1].style.display = "block";
      counter++;
      // } else {
      //   clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Comment: @0stone0 [codepen](https://codepen.io/Lenamm/pen/BaOVoeq)

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, you have declared the `counter` variable twice, once outside the scope of the `animateText` function, and once inside of it.  When animateText is called by setInterval, it passes your outer `counter` variable as an argument, but when you `counter++` inside of `animateText`, you are only incrementing the local variable, not the outer scoped one, and this inner local variable will be lost when the stack frame is discarded.  If you were doing this same thing with an object, rather than a primitive, it would probably work just fine.

One way to solve it is to just remove the `counter` parameter on `animateText` entirely:

```
 const loadingtexts = document.querySelectorAll(".loading-text");
 let counter = 0;

  myInterval = setInterval(() => animateText(), 1000);
  function animateText() {
    if (counter < loadingtexts.length) {
      loadingtexts[counter].style.display = "none";
      loadingtexts[counter + 1].style.display = "block";
      counter++;
    }
  }
```

You also have an off-by-one error in your logic, but I will let you figure that one out :)

Comment: Actually, this is a bad answer, because the interval will keep triggering even after the 4 steps are completed.  Zemichael's answer is better, although he didn't define his `interval` variable, started his counter at 1 instead of 0, and you also shouldn't re-query for all of the elements on every iteration of `animateText`, its just not necessary